# Replacing fragment in an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got this error:

```
No view found for id 0x7f09005b (com.banorte.bepmovil:id/frame) for fragment TransferenciaTercerosFragment{1d548d3 #2 id=0x7f09005b terceros}
```

What I have is an activity that inflates a fragment and later on I want to replace that fragment(1) for another one(2).

So the code in fragment MenuTransFragment(1) to change it to TransferenciaTercerosFragment(2) , the code is this:

```
   private void loadHomeFragment() {

        Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // update the main content by replacing fragments
                Fragment fragment = getFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
                //LinearLayout = LinearLayout


                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

            }
        };

        // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
        if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
            mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
        }
    }
```

geatFragment() basically makes this:

```
TransferenciaTercerosFragment homeFragment = TransferenciaTercerosFragment.newInstance("si","we");
```

The fragment

How can I replace the actual fragment for another one?

Note. Initially for charging the fragment MenuTransFragment(1) I have an activity that uses loadHomeFragment() method.

```
public class ResumenActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements AllAccountsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        AutorizacionesFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        OperacionesFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        TransferenciaTercerosFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
```

@Hamlet Leon

This is the code for onCreateView of 2nd fragment:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transf_terceros, container, false);
    }
```

This is the code of fragment_transf_terceros:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#F1F1F1"
    tools:context=".fragment.TransferenciaTercerosFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="DATOS DE LA TRANSFERENCIA" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Cuenta Origen" />

        <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
            android:id="@+id/ddlOrigen"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@layout/spinner_border">
        </com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Cuenta Destino" />

        <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
            android:id="@+id/ddlDestino"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@layout/spinner_border">
        </com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Importe" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtimporte"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@color/colorCursor"
            android:background="@layout/border"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Número de Referencia" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtreferencia"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@color/colorCursor"
            android:background="@layout/border"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Concepto de Pago" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtconcepto"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@color/colorCursor"
            android:background="@layout/border"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Fecha de aplicación" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfecha"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="295dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="#F1F1F1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/continua_button"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="190dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/btncontinuar" />



    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please post `getFragment()` method. Your explanation of how it works is incomplete.

Comment: Its complete that method just returns the fragment

Comment: You need to show us your TransferenciaTercerosFragment code. Becouse the problem is in there. When you are trying to inflate, it doesnt found the layout resource...

Comment: done @HamletLeon

Comment: And the code for the fragment_transf_terceros.xml?

Comment: added @HamletLeon

Comment: And what about where your container is? (R.id.frame) (Donde esta el id: frame)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176436/discussion-between-hamlet-leon-and-arnoldssss).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works for me was:

```
TransferenciaTercerosFragment homeFragment = TransferenciaTercerosFragment.newInstance("si","we");
                ((ResumenActivity)getActivity()).loadHomeFragment(homeFragment);
```

Modifying homeFragment to receive a fragment in the activity and replacing it.